# Google Calendar api authentication via POST request

Tags: post, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I am trying to issue a POST request towards the google calendar api, but I fail to understand how to authenticate it.

I took the following steps to try and use a service account to do so:

1. I've enabled the the calendar api in the Google Cloud console
2. I've created a new service account, enabled  *G Suite Domain-wide Delegation*, and downloaded the provided key.
3. I've added the service account email to the calendar to be able to make changes and create events.
4. I've tried to create a POST request to https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/**calendarId**/events with the contents of the JSON key as the value of the *Authorization* header, but I receive the following error:

   `{
       "error": {
           "errors": [
               {
                   "domain": "global",
                   "reason": "authError",
                   "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                   "locationType": "header",
                   "location": "Authorization"
               }
           ],
           "code": 401,
           "message": "Invalid Credentials"
       }
   }`

Am I missing some steps or have I do not understand correctly the authentication process?
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  We cant help you without seeing your code and having an idea what language you are using here.

Comment: The request is created using Postman, not a programming language.

Comment: How do you intend to create the access token from a service account using postman?  It would be awesome if you could.  I would love to see how your doing it would make my life a bit easier as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not simply a matter of applying the contents of the key file to your call, all google apis need an access token in order to authenticate them.

To get an access token from a service account you need to follow the following steps. [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests)

There are steps you will need to complete inorder to get the access token you will need to make a call to the api

> After you obtain the client ID and private key from the API Console, your application needs to complete the following steps:
>
> 1. Create a JSON Web Token (JWT, pronounced, "jot") which includes a header, a claim set, and a signature.
> 2. Request an access token from the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server.
> 3. Handle the JSON response that the Authorization Server returns.

I recommend you pick your favorite server sided programming language and find a client library for it.  It will make things much easier then you trying to authncate using a service account by yourself.