# I do not know what to do Insert Calendar in Google Calendar API via Delphi

Tags: delphi, google-calendar-api

I'am using REST components for invite Request for Google Calendar API and insert the calendar.
But I do not know what to do now, because Request response = 401 Unauthorized. I think that using the Header for credentials but I do I do that?
Help me please I new programmer in Delphi...

This my code now

```
    procedure TOAuth2TesterFrm.incluir_btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
json,token: String;
begin
token:=AccessTokenEdt.Text;
json:=(
'{"kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry", "etag": "0", "id": "iago21092020@gmail.com", ' +
'"summary": "Calendario Outro", "description": "Descrição do evento", '   +
'{"date": "2020 August 11", "dateTime": "2020-08-11T17:35:36+03:00"}'+
'"timeZone": "Brasília-DF", "colorId": "15", "backgroundColor": "#9fc6e7", "foregroundColor": "#000000", ' +
'"selected": true, "accessRole": "owner", "primary": true, '+
 '"defaultReminders": [{"method": "popup", "minutes": 30}, {"method": "email", "minutes": 10}], '  +
'"notificationSettings": {"notifications": [{"method": "email", "type": "eventCreation"}, ' +
'{"method": "email", "type": "eventChange"}, {"method": "email", "type": "eventCancellation"}, ' +
'{"method": "email", "type": "eventResponse"}]}}');
try
    client.ResetToDefaults;
    request.ResetToDefaults;
    response.ResetToDefaults;
    client.BaseURL:='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/';
    response.ContentType := 'application/json';
    request.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    request.Body.ClearBody;
    client.AcceptEncoding:='UTF-8';
    client.ContentType:='application/json';
    request.Resource := 'calendars';
    client.Params.AddHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+token);
    client.Params.ParameterByName('Authorization').Options := [poDoNotEncode];
    request.AddBody(json);
    request.Execute;
    ShowMessage(request.Response.StatusCode.ToString);
finally
      request.Free;
      response.Free;
      client.Free;

end;
  end;
```

If I add the commented line, I get an Access Violation error

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62303114/2339326 (it’s c# but explains how a access token should be created - basically a JWT)

Comment: If your token is already a JWT, you need to add the header like ‘Authorization:Bearer <token>’

Comment: I'm already doing this, only because IDHTTP is not the right component, I'm using REST

Comment: In you code you are adding the header as ‘:Token’, but google states you need to use ‘:Bearer’. Second you do not add a space between the the headername/prefix and the token.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my code and no updated her

Comment: I  tried it that way but it doesn't work because the THTTP component is used and I'm using the REST components

Comment: I need learning how to add header in REST components.

Comment: Can you ‘read’ the calendar using the api and token? Of so, then the token does not have the correct rights/rolles specified.

Comment: please edit your question and show us how you are getting your access token.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274129/1841839

Comment: Which scopes are you using for your request? @MárioAyala

Comment: I do not using scopo because I do not know where use, but I have a scopo

Comment: Scopes are added to the token, when creating the token. When you do not have the correct ones added while creating the token, to will probably get ‘authorization sation’ errors. Btw have you tried to send this request using this header in postman or so? Just to make sure that part is ok (or not).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you need to use the TRestClient.Params property to add the header:

```
RestClient.Params.AddHeader(‘Autorization’, ‘Bearer ‘ + token);
```

If you still have problems, you might need to specify the ‘Options’ property of the added parameter: add the option `poDoNotEncode`

Comment: Still cool Unauthorized but thank you very much it helped a lot

Comment: If you do know what the problem is, please post it here

Comment: I do not know what the problem, but I'am trying solve

Comment: @MárioAyala that error message means its not detecting an authorization header.  Your still not setting it right.

Comment: Okay, but I added a header, just like the other friend said

Comment: I trying with Refresh token in URI and with Access token. I  Updated my code for your see.

Comment: I think one thing is missing, the Scope of the API

Comment: Help me somebody!!

Comment: What error are you receiving now? How did you obtain the token? @MárioAyala